# ionic 2 app build fail after install facebook login plugin

Tags: typescript, ionic2, facebook-login

i am developing `Hybrid` app using `ionic-2` in ubantu. i want to add Facebook login in my app but after install Facebook plugin app build fail if i remove Facebook plugin app will build successfully please help me. thank you.

> plugin that i installed

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-facebook4 --variable APP_ID="123456789" --variable APP_NAME="myApplication"
```

> Error message

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 17s
 FAILED
25 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 24 up-to-date
(node:30083) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: /mnt/Workspace/work/project/ionic 2/DrinkOrdering/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
/mnt/Workspace/work/project/ionic 2/DrinkOrdering/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:42: AAPT: error: resource string/fb_app_id (aka drinkordering.com:string/fb_app_id) not found.

/mnt/Workspace/work/project/ionic 2/DrinkOrdering/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:45: AAPT: error: resource string/fb_app_name (aka drinkordering.com:string/fb_app_name) not found.

/mnt/Workspace/work/project/ionic 2/DrinkOrdering/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:49: AAPT: error: resource string/fb_app_name (aka drinkordering.com:string/fb_app_name) not found.

/mnt/Workspace/work/project/ionic 2/DrinkOrdering/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:42: error: resource string/fb_app_id (aka drinkordering.com:string/fb_app_id) not found.
/mnt/Workspace/work/project/ionic 2/DrinkOrdering/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:45: error: resource string/fb_app_name (aka drinkordering.com:string/fb_app_name) not found.
/mnt/Workspace/work/project/ionic 2/DrinkOrdering/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:49: error: resource string/fb_app_name (aka drinkordering.com:string/fb_app_name) not found.
error: failed processing manifest.

Failed to execute aapt
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got a more successful build when I added these lines to the `<resource>` in `platforms/android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml`:

```
    <string name="fb_app_id">APPID</string>
    <string name="fb_app_name">APPNAME</string>
```

The file had these values already, but the string names were different.

I would have liked to put this code in my main `config.xml` but I couldn't get it to work that way. Adding these to `res/values/facebookconnect.xml` or `res/config.xml` also did not work.

Answer (score 2):

It's a common **Cordova issue**

- Run this to fixe it :

  `cordova clean`
- And then build like this :

  `ionic cordova build android`