# Ionic Build Android

Tags: android, ionic-framework, build

I am trying to build an APK for android, and it keeps giving me the following error. I tried everything out there online and never worked. Please help.

```
BUILD FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ‘:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug’.
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/cordova/PermissionHelper.class
Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Total time: 1 mins 51.939 secs
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ‘:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug’.
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/cordova/PermissionHelper.class
Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build android (exit code 1).
```

Comment: which version of ionic cli? which is the exact command you used?

Comment: 3.19  and Ionic cordova build android

Comment: try running `cordova build android --verbose` and see if you get any logs

Comment: Try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46562523/777265)