# Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzew

Tags: ionic3

This happened after I installed OneSignal plugin on my app the build fails at `:transformClassesWithDexForDebug`.

```
:transformClassesWithDexForDebug
 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzew;

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 37.944 secs
(node:9664) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: /home/hamdanihamza/Documents/ionic/Wydad/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzew;
```

Comment: Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46562289/multiple-dex-files-define-lorg-apache-cordova-buildhelper). You might find it informative.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Sorry about that :/