# com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/cordova/Config

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, cordova-chrome-app

I have two modules('app' and 'mlib') in my project and app module depends on mlib module.

In the **mlib** module I am using cordova.jar file as a library.

Now in order to execute any method of mlib module its asking me to add cordova.jar file again. so I added same jar file in my **app** module also. If I am removing jar file from app module, I am getting error

> Cannot access org.cordova.CordovaPlugin

So currently I have cordova.jar file present in both mlib and app module.

Now when I am trying to run the application, I am getting error

> com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/cordova/Config

I have also added below dexOptions in my app level build.gradle file but no luck.

```
dexOptions {
        incremental false
        preDexLibraries = false
        jumboMode = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "2048M"
    }
```

build.gradle file of mlib module:

[image: build.gradle file of mlib module]

Error that I am getting while building:

[image: Error that I am getting while building]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/cordova/BuildHelper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46562289/multiple-dex-files-define-lorg-apache-cordova-buildhelper)

Comment: @GautamSurani I already have checked the link that u are reffering. I am using Android Studio and dont have cordova cli installed in my system So I can't execute  the command mentioed in the other link.