# java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/cordova/PermissionHelper.class

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, wikitude

I'm trying to build my app on android with Cordova and the Wikitude AR plugin. It's working perfectly fine on iOS but once I attempt an android build, it gives me the following error:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/cordova/PermissionHelper.class
```

Removing and adding the platform is not an option. Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: Probable cause and solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46562523/777265

Comment: @DaveAlden I have tried the solutions in that answer, when attempting to remove the compat plugin I get the following `Error: Cannot find plugin.xml for plugin "cordova-plugin-badge". Please try adding it again.`

Comment: That indicates a plugin which is partially present in the project: check for/remove `plugins/cordova-plugin-badge` and check `plugins/fetch.json` for a ghost entry. Failing that I would `rm -Rf plugins/` or re-install all plugins.

Comment: BTW you will may still need to remove/re-add the platform to rebuild it with correct source files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to manually remove the plugin `cordova-plugin-badge` and then `cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-compat --force`.

After I reinstalled `cordova-plugin-compat@1.2.0` and my app built, seemed like the two plugins were tripping up on one another.